# Ansible galaxy: expected a role name in dictionary

Tags: ansible, ansible-galaxy

I have an ansible playbook with roles listed. One of the roles have a tag, and it is ansible galaxy role. I have it installed with ansible-galaxy install.

Playbook part:

```
roles: 
  ... roles here
  - {name: httplab.ffmpeg, tags: ffmpeg}
```

On playbook run I get

```
ERROR: expected a role name in dictionary: {'name': 'httplab.ffmpeg', 'tags': 'ffmpeg'}
```

That's quite confusing message actually. What I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should've been 'role' instead of 'name'.